# How do slope and intercept change for a line when x and y are logged?

Tags: logarithms

I have a linear equation `y = mx + b` that I obtained by fitting a line-of-best-fit to a series of data.

How would I get the equivalent formula if I wanted to plot the same line using log-log axes?

In other words, if the new formula is `log(y) = z*log(x) + c` , what would I have to do to change my original `m` and `b` values to turn them into the `z` and `c` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y=mx+b$, then $\log(y)$ and $\log(x)$ certainly won't be related linearly anymore, so in the equation $\log(y)=z\log(x)+c$, $z$ and $c$ won't be constants.

In fact, if you insist that $z$ and $c$ are constants, then we would have
$$y=10^{\log(y)}=10^{z\log(x)+c}=10^{z\log(x)}10^c = rx^z$$
where $r=10^c$, which is not the same kind of graph as $y=mx+b$.

Comment: So, if I wanted a linear equation for the logged values of x and y, the only way to obtain that would be to log all the x and y values and then re-fit a new line of best fit to the now-logged dataset? And that new line would have no predictable relationship with my original formula y=mx + b ?

Comment: If you truly want a linear equation for the logged values, I don't see any way around redoing the best-fit line. The original $y=mx+b=m(x+b/m)$ would turn into something like $\log(y)=log(x+b/m)+log(m)$ which doesn't really directly relate $\log(y)$ and $\log(x)$ as you're hoping. This would be a linear equation if your axes are labeled $\log(y)$ and $\log(x+b/m)$, but not if they are $\log(y)$ and $\log(x)$.

Comment: I suppose the ultimate question is whether a line better fits x and y data or if it better fits  log(x) and log(y) data (in which case a power law $y=rx^z$ would have fit the original x and y data.